# How can I delete a row from a database from the ListView onClickAdapter?

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, onclick

I want to delete a row in a database with a click from the list view! 
I have everything set up, but when I go to do so it either A) doesn't delete the row. or B) deletes the top row! Let me know what I'm doing wrong! Thanks!

This is in my database:

```
 public boolean deleteKey(String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(KeyEntry.TABLE_NAME, KeyEntry.KEY_ID + "=?",
             new String[]{name})>0;
    }
```

and this is in my list view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view__list);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
    openDatabase();
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, keyList));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, 
            int position, long id)
        {
            String name =  String.valueOf(id);
            keyManager.deleteKey(name);
            Toast.makeText(View_List.this, "Key will be deleted",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter returns the position as `id`. Then the `id` does not match with `KeyEntry.KEY_ID` on database.

The best way to use Database and ListView together is using the CursorAdapter. In this case, the id parameter at onItemClick Listener will be the database id. The CursorAdapter require more code to implement, but it is much more flexible.

Comment: Ok how do I use just the long id to delete the row from the database. Is that possible?